# How to make a one page menu in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm wondering how can I make a menu like in [this website](http://happycog.com/) with Ember ?

The page is split in different sections and we can scroll to go to each section, a click on the menu make the page scroll to the wanted section.

I'm not sure if I should have different routes in the router for this behavior, I would guess it's not the case as when we change route the view is remove from the DOM.
Then, how should I build the anchor link to each section ?

The best solution will automatically updates route when we scroll the page but any solution to handle the link and URL recognition will be fine.

Comment: will you be happy to post your solution back here if you have found one.

Comment: I will be but actually I didn't find a proper solution for this... still waiting for relevant answer.

Comment: ok cheers, if I manage to get a solution, I will also post back here.

Answer (score 1):

Some may argue otherwise, but Ember may be a little overkill for a website landing page like you've shown. Ember is meant more for robust web apps that have multiple views and data they need to be connected with.

First off, if you [look at their script](http://happycog.com/a/j/functions.js), they're using jQuery to animate the `body`'s `scrollTop` position to the respective div and setting `window.location.hash` to the `hash` of the menu element's `href` which also happens to be the ID of the `<section/>` the `body` scrolls to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav a, .clients-capabilities a', function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var hash = this.hash;
    var destination = $(hash).offset().top;

    stopAnimatedScroll();

    $('#nav li').removeClass('on');
    target.parent().addClass('on');

     $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
        scrollTop: destination
    }, 400, function() { window.location.hash = hash; });
    return false;
});
```

Secondly, they are not doing anything special to load to a specific position on page load. If you load any page on the web with a hash, the browser will look for an element with that ID and load at that position. For example, http://emberjs.com/#download.

Even if you still want to use Ember for this, you'd probably end up doing something similar with a single view loaded from the `/` route so I wouldn't even worry about Ember until your site becomes a full fledged web app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Corey! Actually, I do not want this kind of menu for a simple application. I have a full Ember application and I need this kind of menu for one page in the application. I understand how it's made on the website I gave but I need to implement this in a page of an Ember app so the anchor at the end of the URL does not help me.Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `*:` catch all pattern in the router on the page you want to handle this scenario.

so lets say that index will work as a single page that you have to be able to automatically scroll to certain elements from the url.

Also you have **posts** and **about** sub pages that you can go to from the index page via links.

then...

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('posts');
  this.route('index',{path:'*:'});

});
```

so if you have an element with id="elementToScrollTo" then the url /#elementToScrollTo would load the index page and scroll to that element.

See [How to handle 'no route matched' in Ember.js and show 404 page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548594/how-to-handle-no-route-matched-in-ember-js-and-show-404-page) also for some other ways to solve this.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: in your index page use the handlebars {{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}} syntax to get to these routes