# Ember 1.0 Router, try catch on handleURL

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I used to do something like that to catch errors (404s) on ember rc7 :

```
App.Router.reopen({
    handleURL: function(url) {
        try {
            return this._super(url);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
});
```

The catch used to work, but it's not working anymore.

There has been a "router facelift", but I don't understand how it broke that ; and how to catch 404 now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle 'no route matched' in Ember.js and show 404 page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548594/how-to-handle-no-route-matched-in-ember-js-and-show-404-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set up a 404 Route in your router like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.route("404", {
       path: "*:"
   });
});
```

You should be able to then stick custom code (such as your `console.log()`) in the Route's `activate()` and `deactivate()` hooks.